# Problems communicating with USB to Serial CP210x Rs-485 serial device not responding

Tags: python, pi-3, usb, serial, connectors

I have a hardware setup with one lock controller Made in China, I have setted up everything as it was supposed to, trying to communicate with the device with Python Script, lsusb show me the device connected as "Cygnal Integrated Products, Inc. CP210x UART Bridge / myAVR mySmartUSB light" the device address is "ttyUSB0" i have runned several scripts but i am not getting any answer back from the unit, i have even connect it to a Windows machine and run RealTerm and TeraTerm to send hexadecimal strings as the communication protocol of the device dictates, i have setted up the monitor on to see if there is any response and nothing happens.

Baudrate: 9600
parity:none
stopbits=1
Checkbits=No
DateBits=8

this is the comunication protocol:

Communication Agreement

1. Communication interface: RS485
   Baud rate: 9600      Check bits: No       Date bits:  8        Stop bits: 1
2. Plate address query
   The main engine should send the command to the slave plate, the plate address is 0x1 to 0xf, when receive the confirmation reply, we can think the slave plate of the plate address is existence.

   Command header   plate address    Fixation    Status     Check code  (XOR)
   0X81                     0X01 - 0x1F        0X01      0X99       0X18

   Return:
   Command header   Slave plate address    Fixation    Fixation     Check bits 
   0X81              0X01 - 0x1F         0X01      0X99        XXXX
3. Unlock command is below:
   Command   plate address    Lock address    Status     Check code  (XOR)
   0X8A        0X01 - 0x1F             0X01 – 32         0X11         XX

eg: Upper computer send 0X8A  0X02   0X01  0X11  0X98 (hexadecimal), open the control cabinet door, return after 1 second:

Command   plate address   Lock address     Status        Check code
   0X8A        0X02           0X01             0X11         0X98(Lock Open)
   0X8A        0X02           0X01             0X00         0X89(Lock Close)

4. Read the lock status command(The feedback of the door switch status)
   Start   plate address   Lock address   Command    Check code (XOR)
   0X80     0X01 – 0XF            0X00-32       0X33        XX
   The lock address is 0X00, return the status of all of the locks, if it’s not 0, then it will back to this lock status.

   eg:
   a.  Return back to the status of lock 1
   eg: Upper computer send 0X80  0X01   0X01  0X33  0XB2 (hexadecimal),
   return
   Command   plate address   Lock address   Status    Check cod
     (Lock Open)
     0X80        0X01            0X01         0X00      0X80  (Lock Close
   b. Return back to the status of all of the locks:

eg: Host machine send 0X80  0X01   0X00  0X33  0XB2 (hexadecimal),return
Start  plate address  Status1  Status2  Status3  Status4  Status5  Status6 Status7

Command   Check cod
0X80  0X01  0XFF  0XFF  0XFF  0XFF  0XFF  0XFF  0XFF  0X33  0XXX

Status: From status 1 to Status 7, high to low, the corresponding lock is 1-50.

5. Read the agreement identifiers command
   Android main board send the agreement identifiers command to confirm the agreement version number of the lock control board

Start   plate address   Command1   Command2    Check code (XOR)
0X91     0X1-0XF        0XFE        0XFE              0xXX

Return
Start   plate address   Command1   Version NO.    Check code (XOR)
0X91     0X1-0XF        0X6d         0X03              0xXX

so i type the commands directly to the send tab of RealTerm and i just can see the sent command but there is no response.

I am using Python. Code sample next:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

# based on tutorials:
#   http://www.roman10.net/serial-port-communication-in-python/
#   http://www.brettdangerfield.com/post/raspberrypi_tempature_monitor_project/

import serial, time

SERIALPORT = "/dev/ttyUSB0"
BAUDRATE = 9600

ser = serial.Serial(SERIALPORT, BAUDRATE)

ser.bytesize = serial.EIGHTBITS #number of bits per bytes

ser.parity = serial.PARITY_NONE #set parity check: no parity

ser.stopbits = serial.STOPBITS_ONE #number of stop bits

#ser.timeout = None          #block read

#ser.timeout = 0             #non-block read

ser.timeout = 2              #timeout block read

ser.xonxoff = False     #disable software flow control

ser.rtscts = False     #disable hardware (RTS/CTS) flow control

ser.dsrdtr = False       #disable hardware (DSR/DTR) flow control

ser.writeTimeout = 0     #timeout for write

print 'Starting Up Serial Monitor'

try:
    ser.open()

except Exception, e:
    print "error open serial port: " + str(e)
    exit()

if ser.isOpen():

    try:
        ser.flushInput() #flush input buffer, discarding all its contents
        ser.flushOutput()#flush output buffer, aborting current output

        # ser.write (serial.to_bytes([0x80,0x01,0x33,0xB2]))     # Test Line
        ser.write("0X80,0X01,0X00,0X33,0XB2")
        print("write data: Status command")
        time.sleep(0.5)
        numberOfLine = 0

        while True:

            response = ser.readline()
            print("read data: " + response)

            numberOfLine = numberOfLine + 1
            if (numberOfLine >= 5):
                break

        ser.close()

    except Exception, e:
        print "error communicating...: " + str(e)

else:
    print "cannot open serial port "
```